# Lifting degeneracy when operators commute

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra

What is meant by the term "lifting of Degeneracy"? I have been told in my class that if suppose and operator $A$ has some degeneracy, and we have another operator $B$ such that $[A,B] = 0$, then the degeneracy of $A$ can be lifted. What is this exactly? And how commutation leads to loss of degeneracy?

Comment: It means that if a bunch of states have the same eigenvalue under $A$, you can attempt to distinguish them by looking at their eigenvalues under $B$. This is only possible when $A$ and $B$ can be simultaneously diagonalized.

Comment: Okay thanks @ConnorBehan. But can you please tell the procedure of removing the degeneracy and what happens after we have actually removed the degeneracy?
Sorry if I sound extremely stupid. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

We'd need additional context but one interpretation is that you get a second eigenvalue to distinguish between those eigenstates with the same eigenvalue of $A$, i.e the states with eigenvalue $\alpha$ go from arbitrary labelling
$$
\{\vert \alpha,i\rangle, i=1,\ldots, n\}\tag{1}
$$
to
$$
\{\vert \alpha,\beta_1\rangle, \vert \alpha,\beta_2\rangle\ldots,
\vert\alpha,\beta_n\rangle\}
$$
where $\beta_k$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ on states in the subspace spanned by the vectors in (1).  In other words, to "lift" the degeneracy you diagonalize $B$ in the subspace spanned by the states in (1).

Note that there's no guarantee that all $\beta_i$'s are different in that subspace (*i.e.* some pairs $(\alpha,\beta_i)$ might remain identical), so you could still have labelling issues and need a third operator which commutes with $A$ or $B$, or another $B'$ for which the eigenvalues inside (1) are not degenerate.

Comment: What exactly is labelling? 

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean?  You need some ways of labelling (or enumerating) your states...  I mean... the first you label as "1", the second you label as "2" etc. but if they are eigenstates you might as well label them by eigenvalues.

Comment: Does commutation of $A$ and $B$ play any role here?

Thanks

Comment: yes otherwise they would not have a set of *common* eigenvectors, which is what  the $\vert\alpha,\beta_i\rangle$ are.

Comment: Then can we use $A^{\dagger}$ to lift degeneracy of $A$ where $A$ is Hermitian? Because $\left[A, A^{\dagger} \right] = 0$?

Thanks

Comment: if $A$ is hermitian then $A^\dagger=A$ and they have the same set of (degenerate) eigenvalues and eigenvectors so no progress.